# Mounting a shared Google Drive folder

Tags: linux, command-line, mount, file-sharing, google-drive

Is it possible to mount a publicly shared Google Drive folder under Linux?  I've tried all of the normal tools, such as google-drive-ocamlfuse, grive, and gdrivefs, from what I can tell, they only allow you to mount a drive tied to an account you can log into.  That is, they all require authorization of some kind and none of them take a URL as a parameter.  How do I go about mounting a folder not owned by me, one for which the only information I have is a URL?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if that will even be remotely possible till Google gets their crap together and release a proper Linux client.

Maybe using a combination of curl and rsync?  Not quite the same but as close as I can think of it being workable.

The obvious problem is security.  You wouldn't want anyone just having access to files without some sort of authentication or your knowledge just because they have a URL of yours would you?

Comment: OP said that he what's to mount shared public google drive. Security is not matter here.

Comment: Hello 4.5-years-too-late response 